# How to disable function based on condistion - JS

Tags: javascript

Hope someone can help. I'm new to JS and need some help.

I have the following code:

```
}
        function onBall3Click() {
            var ball3 = document.querySelector('.ball3');
            alert('Ball3');

            if (ball3.innerText == 'OFF') {
                ball3.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
                ball3.innerText = 'ON';
            } else if (ball3.innerText == 'ON') {
                ball3.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
                ball3.innerText = 'OFF';
            }
           
        
        }
        function onBall4Click() {
            var ball4 = document.querySelector('.ball4');
            alert('Ball4');
            var size = prompt("What should be the size of the ball?");

            if (size > 1000) {
                alert('Too Big!')
            } else {
                ball4.style.width = size;
                ball4.style.height = size;
            }
```

what I need to know is how to disable function onBall4click when the Ball3.innerText = 'OFF'
and how to enable the function once the Ball3.innerText = 'ON'

Appreciate all the support.

Comment: if the function is triggered via `onclick` property, then you can remove and add it according to your conditions in `onBall3Click` func

Comment: you can run the functions with `addEventListener` and remove it accordingly with `removeEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Javascript but I think all you need to do is add a guard clause in the onBall4click function and check if Ball3 is ON before doing anything. The modified function would look something like this:

```
function onBall4Click() {

    var ball3 = document.querySelector(".ball3");
    if(ball3.innerText === "OFF") return;

    var ball4 = document.querySelector('.ball4');
    alert('Ball4');

    var size = prompt("What should be the size of the ball?");

    if (size > 1000) {
        alert('Too Big!')
    } else {
        ball4.style.width = size;
        ball4.style.height = size;
    }
}
```

When you click on Ball 4, the function checks Ball3 and stops executing if it is off.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked very well! Have a great day.